# How to pass arguments to a Policy's constructor?

Tags: c++, templates

In code:

```
template<class T>
struct FactorPolicy
{
    T factor_;
    FactorPolicy(T value):factor_(value)
    {
    }
};

template<class T, template<class> class Policy = FactorPolicy>
struct Map
{
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
        Map<int,FactorPolicy> m;//in here I would like to pass a double value to a  
 //FactorPolicy but I do not know how.  
        return 0;
    }
```

**Edited** [for Mark H]

```
template<class T, template<class> class Policy = FactorPolicy>
struct Map : Policy<double>
{
    Map(double value):Policy<double>(value)
    {
    }
};
```

Comment: @Alexey if you look at the FactorPolicy's ctor there is a arg to be passed and I would like to be able to pass this value while declaring variable Map. Something like so: Map<int,FactorPolicy(5.5)>

Answer (score 0):

One way is to provide member function templates that take a template arg to use with the policy. For example:

```
template<class T, template<class> class Policy = FactorPolicy> 
struct Map 
{
  template <typename V>
  void foo(const Policy<V> &p)
  {
  }
};
```

Then, in main:

```
Map<int,FactorPolicy> m;

m.foo(FactorPolicy<double>(5.0));
```

Another possibility is to specify it as part of Map template instantiation, by adding a third template arg to Map:

```
template<class T, template<class> class Policy = FactorPolicy, 
         class V = double> 
struct Map 
{
  void foo(const V &value)
  {
    Policy<V> policy(value);
  }
};
```

Then:

```
Map<int,FactorPolicy,double> m;

m.foo(5.0);
```

Comment: @Michael no I didn't, it is a template template class

Comment: OK, so did what I specified for you _tmain function work out? Because the bottom line is you can't define a variable without specifying all of the (actual) template args.

Comment: @Michael to your update, I'm not a 100% sure but if I declare a template template I don't have to provide params in template decl. But as I've said I'm not a 100% sure.

Comment: For template template, your Map definition may be OK, but you definitely have to fill in all of the (template) args to use it for a variable definition.

Comment: @Michael it won't compile what you've typed in _tmain. Just because it is template template. As I've mentioned this already.

Comment: OK, your original code compiles just fine with VC++ 2010, so apparently there is nothing wrong with it other than compiler support in whatever compiler you are using.

Comment: @Michael but there was never problem with compiling it. The whole problem is HOW TO PASS AN ARG TO A FactorPolicy ctor.

Comment: @Michael o just to let you know this arg is going to be of double type.

Comment: I gave you some possible (correct) answers for your question, now that I fully understand it :).

Comment: @Michael thanks for your answer but I want to avoid specifying separately the value of the policy (outside of the actual variable definition). If that wasn't the case I could build Map's ctor with a double type to be provided and this is even simpler than yours solution.;)

Comment: If you do not want to go through these hoops, perhaps you are parameterizing Map too much? Perhaps you shouldn't use template template and just allow for a concrete type for Policy?

Comment: @Michael let's assume that I would consider doing what've you suggesting. How then I could pass this arg?

Answer (score 0):

If you were to pass a double, it would require that the type argument of FactorPolicy be double inside Map, unless you make the FactorPolicy constructor to accept a double. I don't think that is what you want though. You must inform Map that Policy needs a double, so first add that type argument. Secondly, I think you will need to forward the actual double value from the Map constructor.

```
template<class T, typename U, template<class> class Policy = FactorPolicy >
struct Map {
    Map(U val) {
        policy_ = new Policy<U>(val);
    }

    Policy<U>* policy_;
};

int main()
{
    Map<int, double, FactorPolicy> m(5.63);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Mark if I would want to pass the factor value to the ctor I would do it even simpler - you do not have to specify U type.

Comment: For what you are claiming, you would need to define it as `template<class T, class Policy = FactorPolicy<double> >`. Else how is Map going to know that FactorPolicy needs a double? It can't simply deduce that from the type of the argument, you must expicitly state the type somewhere.

Comment: Your update requires you to pass an `int`. FactorPolicy still doesn't know what a `double` is.

Comment: But now Policy is non-generic. You can't use it with anything other than a double. (Unless you are using a different Policy to the one you're passing the double to)

Comment: @Mark That's what I wanted, but if you change the double type to T it will also work as intended. The type will be deduced from Map ctor.